# Retrieving "to" field in GetStream.io

Tags: getstream-io

Returning to some code from a year or more ago, I find that the "to" field is not being returned when getting a user feed or flat feed. This appears to be the case using both the realtime javascript client and the Python library. The field is returned when adding an activity in the first place.

In my system, users subscribe to the "to" feeds rather than the feeds of the actors themselves. The presence of the 'to' field makes it possible to show the user why an activity has appeared in their feed. "To" fields to which the user is subscribed are highlighted within each activity, and activities bearing multiple highlighted 'to' fields stand out as being of greater interest.

Is this element no longer returned, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'to' field is included on Activities when the feed they were originally added to is retrieved. However when a feed is retrieved that contains an Activity that arrived there via 'to' field targeting, that Activity won't include the 'to' field.

Comment: Thank you Dwight. That's new, I guess? I need to handle this somehow. For me, the 'to' field is as important as the actor.

Comment: Best to contact Stream to discuss this further.